# Resizing Custom UITableViewCell Height and Height of UITextView in that Cell (with other UI elements present)

Tags: ios, dynamic, uitableview, height, uitextview

I have a custom table cell that contains 3 labels, a button, and a UITextView.

The text for the UITextView is only known at runtime as it's data I'm pulling from a server.

I'm trying to size both my UITextView and my Custom Table Cell to the correct height based on the text that I put into the UITextView.

The text for the UITextView gets set in the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method.

In here I'm trying to size the UITextView (bodyTextView) using the following..

```
CGSize stringSize = [cell.bodyTextView.text sizeWithFont:cell.bodyTextView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(cell.bodyTextView.bounds.size.width, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

[cell.bodyTextView setText:threadMessage.body];

CGRect bodyFrame = cell.bodyTextView.frame;

bodyFrame.size = cell.bodyTextView.contentSize;

[cell.bodyTextView setFrame:bodyFrame];
```

That more or less seems to be working fine either that my UIButton isn't moving down to where it should even though it has a "Top Space To" constraint to the bottom of my UITextView. I would've thought that it would've automatically moved. However I can move this to the appropriate location programatically so not a big deal.

The next bit of code does size the tableViewCell to the appropriate height to fit in the labels and the UITextView but there isn't enough space for the button at the bottom.
Next I calcuate the height of the cell and return it using the following...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize stringSize = [threadMessage.body sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    float oldHeight = 28;
    float newHeight = stringSize.height;

    return tableView.rowHeight - oldHeight + newHeight;
}
```

As you can see I'm doing a difference in height between what the UITextView height was and what the new one is. I tried to get the oldHeight programatically but I was getting crazy values in the many thousands.

The big problem is that when the view first shows, the row is sized, more or less, correctly. But the UITextView isn't sized. If I scroll to move it off screen and then scroll it back then the UITextView is sized properly. But then again if I scroll it off and back on screen it's resized itself again to a single line.

I feel I have a chicken or the egg thing going on and can't get my head around this.

The two main issues I'm hoping to get figured out are :

1 ) How to get the UITextView to size properly right from the start and stay that way regardless of scrolling off and on screen?

2 ) How to get my custom TableCellView to size appropriately to include the height of the button?

I hope this all makes sense and I've provided enough detail. Let me know of any questions.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally figured out the issues. Thought I would post my solution in case anyone else runs into this as this twisted my brain for many hours today.

I thought the issue may have something to do with my project using the iOS 6 SDK. I downloaded the iOS 5 Simulator and tried running my app on that. I got an error immediately after it started. NSLayoutInconsitencyException (or something similar to that). After some digging around with some online searches I found out that iOS 5 is not compatible with a setting from iOS 6.

This setting was "User Autolayout" and it was check on in my storyboard file. To find it, select your storyboard file and then select File Inspector on the right (Command-Option-1). Under the Interface Builder Document section you will see the checkbox for "Use Autolayout". Uncheck this and things started working a lot better. No longer was my UITextView being resized to one line and back to full length each time I scrolled the cell on and off the screen.

However I still had an issue with the cell not quite being the right height. This turned out to be very simple now that I had cleared up the Autolayout problem (you wouldn't believe all the commented out trial and error test code I had everywhere :) ).

In the cellforRowAtIndexPath function you need to set the UITextView's text to whatever you want it to be and then simple get it's contentSize and then resize the frame of your UITextView...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];

    [cell.bodyTextView setText:myText];

    CGRect bodyFrame = cell.bodyTextView.frame;
    bodyFrame.size = cell.bodyTextView.contentSize;
    [cell.bodyTextView setFrame:bodyFrame];

    ... Whatever else you need to do here ...
}
```

Then in heightForRowAtIndexPath I found that getting a cell again and setting the text I was able to get the proper size difference and therefore return the proper size. By using a size difference it allows for any other UI elements you may have in your table cell.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"]; 

    float oldHeight = cell.bodyTextView.frame.size.height;

    cell.bodyTextView.text = threadMessage.body;

    CGRect bodyFrame = cell.bodyTextView.frame;
    bodyFrame.size = cell.bodyTextView.contentSize;

    float newHeight = cell.bodyTextView.contentSize.height;

    return tableView.rowHeight - oldHeight + newHeight;
}
```

I hope this helps someone in the future. Feel free to ask me any questions if any of this didn't make sense. Thanks to Mohit for trying to help me out. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Etep, just try this... first of all you off the resize/orientation property of cell and button, and after that as you are able to make proper dimension of text-view as per your arriving text so where you're computing the row height, instead of using getting text size, what you need to get the proper height of your text-view... and rest is fine.(in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath', you should make use of reusable cell, or say put your code inside the if (cell==nil){})

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mohit! I am using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to reuse cells, just didn't put it in the code above. :) As for the rest, I admit I'm not sure I follow? I'm not sure what you mean by the resize/orientation property of cell and button? Did you mean turn off? How? Also you mention that instead of getting text size (this is the one thing that is working properly) I should get the height of the textView? I assume using frame.size.height? I tried that but the text isn't written to the textview yet since heightForRoawAtIndexPath gets called before cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: As I found that your button position at wrong position for this the only thing might be happen that your cell auto-resize the subviews so just uncheck that property from the IB and also check the window option where your component will be seen and, the most important thing is that your row height should vary accordingly to the textview not to that as you used as they never be equal.Also, you can know when your textfield is filled with your data and after that just explicitly call the heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Can you provide me the url from which you getting the data, so I can make sample and tell you accordingly :)

Comment: I just tested with some fake data, and what I did first I assumed my textView size to some max limit say half of screen and start the process and at when my downloading accomplished I checked that data from array and after that I reload table with right calculation...

Comment: Well I figured out a major issue. I was using iOS 6 SDK and the storyboard had "Use Autolayout" checked on. I unchecked this (and also went Simulator 5.0) and that cleared up the issue with the UITextView changing sizes upon scrolling the table view. Now I have just have to get the right row height. The height is just off by a little bit if their is a small amount of data but this increases as the more text there is. My code above is shorting the height of the row the more text there is in the textview.

Comment: Mohit, could you post some sample code on pastie.org and post the url here?

Comment: Cheers you sort-out :) And, that's the same which I suggest you by mentioning orientation(as just skipped the proper name)... Sorry, can't be able to post now but will do after sometime... :)

Comment: Glad that you sorted-out, and also if you need find this url "http://pastie.org/5422536" but this is only for testing purpose as for now I don't think for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this same issue while autoresizing custom cells on rotating. After fighting I got the solution as authorize cell.contentView, because I am adding my views as subview into cell.contentview.

I used following code and my code works fine :)

```
cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```